# I have created https endpoints for alexa custom skills using PHP. It was working fine in test simulator But not working on alexa app

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created custom skills and https endpoints using PHP.
I have tested skills on simulator it was working. I am able to see my skills on alexa android app and i have enabled it. But not getting valid response.

Comment: What is the response that you are expecting? and what is the response that you receiving?Some code snippets and steps to replicate would be helpful

Comment: @ValerianPereira I just created sample skill with invocation name " mytrip ". If i say "Alexa, open mytrip", In test simulator i am getting " Hi, Welcome to PlanMyTrip. How Can I help you to make your trip plan? ". But in from alexa app I am getting " Sorry, i am not sure " message

Comment: Could you rename your invocation name temporarily and use your skill? Looks like Alexa resolves to `PlanMyTrip` when the keyword `mytrip` is identified.

Comment: I reffered this blog : http://blog.gaiterjones.com/amazon-alexa-php-hello-world-example/

Comment: @ValerianPereira Ya, i renamed my inocation name But still not getting. Is there any way to find the error what we are getting when we make request from alexa app for custom skills ? Is it possible to test custom skills in alexa app which is in developement mode ?

Comment: Can you check the language settings in your simulator, the android app and the skill that you built? It should be the same.

Comment: Did you Enable the skill in the Alexa App? If it is already enabled, try disabling and enable again.

Answer (score 1):

The Language of your Interaction Model should match to the region your lambda snippet is deployed. 
Default language for interaction model is English (US)
For E.g 
Change the language to English(UK)
Interaction Model - English (UK)
Lamda Resource - English (UK)

Comment: Yes, my region language is English(US) for both simulator and interaction model. How can i test my skills on amazon Alexa app ?

Comment: The Alexa App too should have the same language.

Comment: How to change alexa app language to our current region English(IN) ?